# javascript with checkbox to count and hide/show

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

i need help to make one script

The script I'm trying to do is the following:

I have a page with multiple checkbox's corresponding products and they all have an associated value.
  then I have a variable that is the value I have in the account, and what I wanted to do with that as I start choosing products by clicking on the checkbox, javascript would have to count the value that has already been chosen and see how and lacking and hide all products that have a higher value or have available

```
<?php
$totalmoney = '50';
?>
<div class="tags">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="arts" value="20" /> Arts </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="computers" value="40" /> Computers </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="phone" value="15"/> Phone </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="video-games" value="5" /> Video Games </label>
</div>
```

Help me please, i need this to my work :S

Comment: Your job is paying *you* to do this work. Not *us*.

Comment: No I am not being paid, I'm just developing a website for the company of my brother, and I did not ask to do my job, just ask for help that is what this site serves simple. but thanks anyway;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with calculating the values of selected checkboxes with JS something like this:

```
var $inputs = $('#arts,#computers,#phone,#video-games');
$inputs.on('click', function (event) {
  $checked = $inputs.is(':checked');
  totalChecked = 0;
  $checked.each(function () {
    totalChecked += $(this).val();
  });
});
```

Now you can easily check the rest:

```
var toBeSpend = totalmoney - totalChecked;
$inputs.not(':checked').each(function () {
  $(this).toggle($(this).val() > toBeSpend);
});
```